# Could you recommend development integrated tool when develop web client application

Tags: java, javascript, html

Using JavaScript, HTML and CSS, the server is Java. What is the good develeopment tool to develop the web client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse IDE and NetBeans are 2 most dominant IDE's for Java written in Java. These 2 is designed for Web Development in mind as well as others. Did I mention that both are also free?

Comment: Does Eclipse mean "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers"?

Comment: No, Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. It have full functionality of Web Development inclusive for the java platforms. I've never used Eclipse IDE for Javascript Web Developers personally.

Answer (score 1):

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) = Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I do like Eclipse, but your question is too open ended, you should at least specify what you're looking for in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

ID eclipse, [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can start with either Eclipse or Netbeans, both are good for web development. Some others will opt for [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html)

Comment: I was referring to people who think the two top IDEs suck big time and IDEA is their best, although i honestly never used it. You can find such geeks in `##java` on [Freenode IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net)

Comment: Does Eclipse mean "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers"?

Comment: @user496949 No i haven't tried that specific download and i was referring to the JEE edition.

Comment: Rather say, "some" because you never know if many others might be Vim guys, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Eclipse, Aptana and ended up deciding that paying for WebStorm/PhpStorm was definitely worth it! It has the best hierarchical view of JS content, auto-complete, usage search, plus a built-in debugger. Aptana has many of the same features, they just don't work as well. Plus Aptana is reeeeeeeealy slow!